# jruby-openssl depends on non-existent bouncy-castle-java version?

Tags: jruby, bouncycastle, jruby-openssl

I'm trying to install jruby-openssl, but it depends on a bouncy-castle-java version that doesn't appear to exist.  Anybody know how to work around this?

```
$ gem install jruby-openssl 
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: jruby-openssl requires bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0147)
```

I tried installing an older version of jruby-openssl, but it didn't seem to help.

```
$ gem install jruby-openssl 0.7
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: jruby-openssl requires bouncy-castle-java (>= 1.5.0147)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

> gem install redcar --both --no-force

bouncy-castle-java-1.5.0147 Will be installed too.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had a link for you because I don't really understand exactly what happened, but I had the same issue. I saw on Twitter that there was an issue with the 0.8.4 release. I have no idea why downgrading to 0.8.2 didn't fix it, but they've released a fix in 0.8.5 and it seems to work for me.

(Not very informative, but here's the tweet: https://twitter.com/jruby/status/312314690313269248)